# You'll be okay. Vs. You're gonna be okay

Tags: modal-verbs, semi-modals

I heard you use Will for the facts and something that you believe as true, and Be going to to show simple prediction or something about to happen. Then which is the strong sentence between those on the title? And how?

Let say there's two situations.

> A: Will I be all right?
>
> B: Well, you're gonna be okay.

and

> A: Am I gonna be all right?
>
> B: Well, you will be okay.

Then what's the differences between those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of these have the same meaning, and are quite similar. The only real difference is that "You will be okay" is more formal, and the person saying it sounds more sure of themselves and the sentence is therefore more reassuring.

"You're gonna be okay" is less formal and more casual, something someone would say to a friend, but would still be reassuring despite that.